# InAppbrowser window.open plugin for Cordova 3.5 not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, window.open, inappbrowser

InAppBrowser's method .open() not working in my app.
Using Cordova 3.5 and plugin's version 0.4.1 from InAppBrowser plugin.

Tried the given example:

```
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

But doesn't work.

If I build the app with
cordova run android
the app is installed into my device and nothing happens when I click the link with the onclick calling the above code.
Same with
cordova serve
and accessing through localhost:8000 (local browser).

If I emulate through ripple (with ripple emulate), when I access the page (`localhost:4400/`) and click at the link, the page is reloaded with the content:
"InAppBrowser Emulation
It is like a browser, only it is all up in your app

```
URL: http://apache.org/
TARGET: _blank
OPTIONS: "location=yes"
```

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Update:

We were getting different results when the project was built on different machines. We found that the issue was caused by an untracked file:

```
[cordova project folder]/plugins/android.json (or other OS : ios.json)
```

We found each machine had a different plugin order. When we started tracking the file and fixed the plugin order then the problem went away. You may want to remove the plugin on all machines then add it again.

I'm not sure why the order matters, you would think it shouldn't but it does.

Adding the file, syncing repositories and rebuilding fixed the issue.

Try using _system instead of _blank.

Original:

Also, for iOS I had to use something like this:

```
 <a onclick="window.open('http://google.ca', '_system')" >iOS</a>
```

But on Android I had to use :

```
<a onclick="navigator.app.loadUrl('http://google.com', {openExternal : true})" >Android</a>
```

Comment: Something is wrong with both of you -- the OP's code works fine for me in iOS and Android as is. My sample looks like: <button style="margin:1em;padding:1em;"><a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://play.google.com/', '_blank', 'location=yes');">Our Apps</a></button>

Comment: @Steve Thanks for your feedback. I tested your example using cordova 3.5 on Android 4.4.2 with the InAppBrowser plugin 0.4.1. After adding the missing url protocal, and removing the extraneous semicolon it still did not work for me on Android.

Answer (score 2):

I also have the same problem, I found the solution:

```
    var ref=window.open(encodeURI(url), '_blank', 'location=no,closebuttoncaption=Main');
    ref.addEventListener('exit', function()
```

Use this code to open the url.It will work

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I "fixed" it by calling the Cordova function directly:

```
cordova.exec(successFunction, errorFunction, "InAppBrowser", "open", ['http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes']);
```

Hopefully that works for you.